# Bindings for custom views for NSCollectionViewItem

Tags: cocoa, cocoa-bindings, nscollectionview, nscollectionviewitem

I've got a `NSCollectionView` bound to my array of model objects, the `NSView` prototype to render items of the collection view is set up to use my custom `NSView` subclass.

At runtime a (generic) view is shown/instantiated in the collection view for each array element, all good.

However, I just can't figure out how to get to my array objects from the individual view instances to render the actual data that's specific to each element in the array.
I.e. how are we supposed to hook up data to the `NSView` prototype that is used to configure a 'cell' in the collection view?

- **Outlets** don't seem to work for that particular view; they're all `nil` at runtime.
- **Bindings** don't work with a vanilla `NSView` (apart from *hidden* and *tooltip* bindings for vanilla views..) - and we cannot add new bindings that would show up in IB for our `NSView` subclasses, can we?

Any hint appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nevermind - I've settled with a custom `NSCollectionView` class overriding only

`- (NSCollectionViewItem *)newItemForRepresentedObject:(id)object`

to access the item view of `NSCollectionViewItem` instances created by `super` and set the required property there.